# Compile Angular 2 node_modules files into one file

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I am trying to figure out a way to compile everything I need from the angular 2 node_modules folder into one file.. It seems that there is a crazy amount of http calls when my site is loading and surely thats not optimal or the recommended process of the new and improved angular..

Im not concerned with my own typescript files as i know how to handle them but what are your approaches to concatenating the node_modules files etc ?

Comment: use webpack with createCommonChunk plugin, awesome tool

Answer (score 3):

If you're using **SystemJS**

---

**1.** **`package.json`** : add these to `devDependencies`

```ts
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.16"
  }
```

**2.** do `npm install`

**3.** create **gulpfile.js** at the same level of `index.html`, with this content in it

```ts
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  Builder = require('systemjs-builder');


gulp.task('bundle-angular-dependencies', function() {
  // optional constructor options
  // sets the baseURL and loads the configuration file
  var builder = new Builder('', 'systemjs.config.js');

  return builder
    .bundle('app/boot.js - [app/**/*.js]', 'path/to/put/angular.bundle.js', { minify: true})
    .then(function() {
      console.log('Build complete');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Build error');
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

**4.** open terminal and go to the directory of your project. do `gulp bundle-angular-dependencies`

**5.** Reference `angular.bundle.js` in your `index.html`, below `system.js` but above `system.config.js`.

---

*If you have any queries, let me know.*

Comment: This looks interesting. what does your systemjs.config.js file look like

Comment: same as Angular2 QuickStart Guide

Comment: Not working,It's still calling all those dependency files and angular.bundle.js....

Answer (score 0):

I've read through the github discussions about this and as far as I am aware there is no native bundling support, however I have created a gulp task that gets you 3/4 of the way there.

If you are using SystemJS, you can use the systemjs-builder package to bundle up all of angular 2's dependencies into one file. This file comes out at about 95k, which is quite reasonable; and as you probably guessed, load time goes down significantly (<1s). Note that Angular still tries to pull the custom packages (e.g. lodash/underscore) you have defined in the system-config file so I end up just copying these modules into the /dist folder with another gulp task (though you can do it manually if you are only bundling for production.)

This is a project in itself and if you started your project before the angular-cli came out, you will likely need to do heavy restructuring of your files to meet their standard directory structure.

The basic gist for the bundling gulp task is here: https://gist.github.com/stewhouston/27cac18c64d03b14de8b39389cbaa1c5. I have several other gulp tasks that are used in the bundling process and can paste them if you'd like, though if you can't write them yourself by that point the bundling process will be pretty excruciating.

Hopefully the angular 2 team release a native bundler soon to make this all unnecessary.

Comment: Hi Stew yeah that would be great.. Im starting to regret getting into angular 2 already. Like it seems like an awful lot of extra work. The only plus side is being able to say hey look at my site its using cutting edge technologies... the time investement vs reward doesnt weigh up for me but unfortunately im already knee deep in building my new site using it and laravel.. any scripts you have are much appreciated, Im a grunt man myself but I dont mind digging into gulp

Comment: @user3461985 Ang2 came out of beta less than a month ago and lots of people are complaining that it was released too early. I agree to some degree, though my app is shaping up nicely. If you are using Laravel and will be doing templating in your PHP scripts Angular 2 might not be the best choice. It pretty much wants to be the primary engine for your entire project with the exception of any services you are running to handle database interaction. Laravel is pretty beefy and I think the drawbacks of using Angular 2 outweight the benefits. Just my honest opinion.

Comment: With that being said, if you decide to continue on, here is the relevant parts of my gulpfile: https://gist.github.com/stewhouston/0ad5cd21d881f0533985670d11aab678 -- I am still in dev mode so edit as necessary.