# I'm trying to find an angular2 app that has gulp for creating a dist folder using the latest @angular libraries

Tags: angularjs, angular, gulp

I'm trying to find an angular2 app that has gulp for creating a dist folder using the latest @angular libraries.

I can find some online but they dont use latest @angulae libs and gulp.

I'm also using system.js to boot the app locally, so I need to see an example of how that works for a dist deployment folder thats bundled.

My main requirements for the app I'm trying to build is:

- Gulp.
- Angular2.
- Latest Angular 2 libs with http and routing libs added.
- System.js used.
- Typescript.
- All the ts files bundles into one file for dist folder.

**This is my main.ts file:**

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, ROUTER_BINDINGS, RouterOutlet, RouteConfig, RouterLink, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, CanActivate, OnActivate,
    ComponentInstruction} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

if ('<%= ENV %>' === 'prod') { enableProdMode(); }

import {AuthService} from './services/authService/authService';
import {SocialService} from './services/socialService/socialService';
import {UserService} from './services/userService/userService';
import {OrganisationService} from './services/organisationService/organisationService';
import {NotificationService} from './services/notificationService/notificationService';
import {ApplicationService} from './services/applicationService/applicationService';
import {JobService} from './services/jobService/jobService';
import {MessageService} from './services/messageService/messageService';
import {EmailService} from './services/emailService/emailService';

import {Environment} from './models/environment/environment';

import {LoggedInRouterOutlet} from './interceptor';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>' }),
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    Environment,
    AuthService, 
    ApplicationService,
    EmailService,
    SocialService, 
    UserService,
    JobService,
    MessageService, 
    EmailService, 
    OrganisationService, 
    NotificationService
]);
```

**Folder Structure And Git Bash Error**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for exactly the same thing, and it's been challenging, especially when it comes to bundling.

[This repo](https://github.com/madhukard/angular2-jspm-seed) has what you're asking for (as far as I can tell), but it's far more complicated than I'm hoping for. And its build is currently failing.

Last night I was finally able to get this working, but I haven't checked to see whether source maps and such are going to work. I started by following the [5-minute quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) pretty closely (i.e. make sure you're using the version of Node they recommend), but making a few adjustments based on my project's setup.

#### gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var cached = require('gulp-cached');
var remember = require('gulp-remember');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var SystemBuilder = require("systemjs-builder");

var paths = {
    dist: 'client/dist',
    tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json'
}

gulp.task('scripts:startup', function() {
    return gulp.src([
            'core-js/client/shim.min.js',
            'zone.js/dist/zone.js',
            'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js'
        ], { cwd: 'node_modules' })
        .pipe(concat('startup.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('client/dist'));
});


gulp.task('scripts:app', function() {
    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));
    return tsResult.js
        //.pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps', { includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '/client/app' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('client/dist/app'));
});

gulp.task('scripts:bundle',
    function () {
        var builder = new SystemBuilder('.', 'systemjs.config.js');
        return builder.buildStatic('app', 'client/dist/app.js');
    });

gulp.task('scripts', ['scripts:startup', 'scripts:app', "scripts:bundle"]);

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles'], function () {
});
```

#### package.json

```
{
    ...
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "tsc",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "postinstall": "typings install",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "typings": "typings"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
        "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.7",
        "gulp-cached": "^1.1.0",
        "gulp-remember": "^0.3.1",
        "gulp-typescript": "~2.13.4",
        "systemjs-builder": "~0.15.19",
        "typescript": "~1.8.10",
        "typings": "~1.0.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",

        "systemjs": "0.19.27",
        "core-js": "^2.4.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

        "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.11",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
    }
}
```

#### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Precise Patient Registry</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="client/dist/startup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="client/dist/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <ppr-app>Loading...</ppr-app>

</body>
</html>
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "node_modules/typescript",
        "typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

#### typings.json

```
{
    "globalDependencies": {
        "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654",
        "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160505161446",
        "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515"
    }
}
```

#### systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'client/dist/app', 
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade'
    ];
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    }
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Also, if you've already got a project that has stuff from an older version of angular, be sure to prune npm and typings:

```
npm prune
npm install
npm run typings prune
```

Otherwise the old polyfills tend to get in the way of typescript compiling.

Please, *please*, keep me updated if you make improvements to this. I've been spending far too much time trying to get this stuff all figured out, and I'd love to get some collaborative feedback.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the large answer. I'm searching loads also. I will keep you in the loop as well. I will trying your answer now. Thank you and I will be in touch shortly

Comment: This is my current question I made for trying to solve system.js working in a dist folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525356/how-to-create-an-angular-2-build-folder-when-using-systemjs-config-js

Also, I have been following this link: https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html#angular2-google-maps-setup

But cant turn it into a build dist folder with my gulp

Comment: have you tried getting the above app working for lexith?

Comment: @AngularM: No, I haven't seen the seed project that lexith pointed to. It looks promising. BTW, I made a slight update to my code above based on a bug that I realized I had.

Answer (score 1):

**Angular2 Seed by Minko Gechev** is probably exactly what you are looking for:

https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

It follows the [official Angular2 style guide](https://angular.io/styleguide) (which i think he also works on). So basically a pretty good starting point for training projects and probably for production projects as well.

---

A more lightweight seed would be from the [angular2 team itself](https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed). But the `systemjs` branch is not yet updated to angular2 rc1. But updating it yourself wouldn't be so hard, since the basic setup could stay the same.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go now

Comment: Works really well. thank you. How would I add firebase to this eg so it would add the typings so the it would recognise Firebase word when i use it in my typescritp

Comment: Maybe you should ask this in a seperate question if you can't find out. I never worked with Firebase yet, so i can't help you, i'm sorry.

Comment: I'm having trouble doing a build now that ive merged our apps together. im trying to do a prod build. Its having trouble fetching my home.js file for my homepage in git bash.

Comment: I've basically got lots of services, models, components all added to the main.ts file but they seem to cause trouble on build.prod. any ideas?

Comment: I've added my main.ts file above

Comment: I've also added a screen grab above of my folder structure and gitbash error. I wonder if its something todo with the fact that my files are store in a folder called components where yours wasnt? not sure how to change that in your settings though if thats the case

Comment: the error might be somewhere in your "merge" process you talked of. you probably should try adding your components step by step to find the error. only with your main.ts file and your screen it's really hard to find out where the problem is

Comment: I've been using https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed and the theoretical step to creating a distribution is `npm run build.prod`.  This does all the required work and writes to `dist`, however that happens in 2 directories - `dist/prod` and `dist/tmp`.  I can't work out why.